# Como deserializar un XML con estructura variable en C# .NET

Tags: c#, xml, serializacion

Normalmente deserializo objetos XML con una estructura fija y preparo una clase para eso usando etiquetas XmlElement o XmlAttribute.

Cuando es un arreglo lo hago de la siguiente forma:

```cs
public class ClaseEtiquetaPrincipal
{
   [XmlAttribute]
   public string Nombre { get; set; }
   [XmlAttribute]
   public bool Update { get; set; }
   [XmlArray("Numeros"), XmlArrayItem("Numero")]
   public Numero[] Numeros { get; set; }
}
public class Numero
{
   [XmlAttribute]
   public int valor { get; set }
   [XmlAttribute]
   public string otro { get; set }
}
```

Pero ahora necesito deserializar un XML con unas etiquetas que pueden cambiar. Pueden tener mas o menos y de valores diferentes.

**Por Ejemplo**

```xml
<Request>
  <Algo>2</Algo>
  <Personas>
    <Persona>
       <nombre>Paco</nombre>
       <edad>35</edad>
       <direccion>Donde sea</direccion>
    </Persona>
    <Persona>
       <nombre>Paco</nombre>
       <edad>35</edad>
       <direccion>Donde sea</direccion>
       <otro>12-12-2019</otro>
       <algomas>1234312</algomas>
    </Persona>
  </Personas>
</Request>
```

He probado usar la clase XElement de la siguiente forma:

```cs
public XElement[] personas { get; set; }
```

Pero cuando quiero serializar de vuelta me agrega una estructura de más y no me sirve porque debo enviarla a una base de datos.
Queda algo asi:

```xml
<XElement>
  <Personas>
    <Persona>
       <nombre>Paco</nombre>
       <edad>35</edad>
       <direccion>Donde sea</direccion>
    </Persona>
    <Persona>
       <nombre>Paco</nombre>
       <edad>35</edad>
       <direccion>Donde sea</direccion>
       <otro>12-12-2019</otro>
       <algomas>1234312</algomas>
    </Persona>
  </Personas>
</XElement>
```

Ahora mismo estoy investigando como usar clases dinamicas pero me gustaria saber si hay alguna forma de hacer esto.

Comment: Agrega un metodo generico aun cuando cambie la estructura este se adaptara al tipo de elemento que tiene tu base de datos.

Comment: como es eso de etiquetas que pueden cambiar, entonces no vas a poder deserializar a uan clase, vas a tener que usar codigo dinamico con liqn to xml o XmlDocument aplicando selectores sobre los nodos, esa tecnica de deserializar no aplica a un xml sin una estructura definida

Comment: @LeandroTuttini Las etiquetas que cambian son solo los campos del objeto persona del ejemplo. El resto de la estructura es fija. Soy algo novato en .NET donde puedo buscar mas info sobre "linq to xml" o el uso de selectores con XmlDocument?

Comment: no importa que solo cambie una parte, no vas a poder deserializar a una estructura predefinida si algo no puede definirse, no al menos de la forma en que lo planteas, si puede usar otras tecnicas que vayan tomando los nodos por sus nombres

Answer (score 1):

Intenta utilizar el objeto XmlSerializer para extraer los datos de tu xml

ejemplo:

```
private void DeserializeObject(string filename)
    {   
        Console.WriteLine("Reading with Stream");
        // Create an instance of the XmlSerializer.
        XmlSerializer serializer = 
        new XmlSerializer(typeof(OrderedItem));

        // Declare an object variable of the type to be deserialized.
        OrderedItem i;

        using (Stream reader = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
        {
            // Call the Deserialize method to restore the object's state.
            i = (OrderedItem)serializer.Deserialize(reader);          
        }

        // Write out the properties of the object.
        Console.Write(
        i.ItemName + "\t" +
        i.Description + "\t" +
        i.UnitPrice + "\t" +
        i.Quantity + "\t" +
        i.LineTotal);
    }
```

Comment: Creo que no entendí muy bien tu respuesta. Me podrias explicar un poco mas por favor? Con extraer los datos te refieres a las distintas etiquetas que pudieran venir? Gracias por tu respuesta